# How to force installation of package to site-packages using pip from VCS

Tags: python, git, pip, setup.py, distutils

I'm trying to install {my_package} from VCS (GIT) in such way

- conda activate {env}
- cd {path}
- pip install -e git+git@{REPO}.git@{branch}#egg={my_package}

After successful installation I imported {my_package} and get the right result for all tests. But:

- I check PYTHON/envs/{env}/Lib/site-packages and didn't find {my_package} folder. Found only such file {my_package}.egg-link with the following content "{path}\src{my_package} \n."
- I opened this path and found {my_package} installed there

How to force installation of {my_package} to PYTHON/envs/{env}/Lib/site-packages/{my_package}?

Thank you.

PS - installation with git clone -> python setup.py install works fine and install {my_package} to the right folder PYTHON/envs/{env}/Lib/site-packages/{my_package}

Comment: "*Found only such file {my_package}.egg-link*" This is the result of **-e** in `pip install -e`.

Comment: And how I can change my command for installation from VCS? `pip install git+git@{REPO}.git@{branch}#egg={my_package}` won't work.

Comment: `git clone git@{REPO}.git && cd {REPO} && git checkout {branch} && pip install .`

Comment: @phd Maybe you know, is that possible to include third party packages to requirements.txt?

Comment: Like this: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers ?